# Z Test basic problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test

The mean selling price of new homes in a town over a year was \$2,200,000. The population standard deviation is \$200,000 . A random sample of 81 new home sales from this city was taken. What is the probability that the sample mean selling price was more than \$2,500,000?

**My Doubt -**

In the solution which I have, the solution completely ignored the value of sample size (which is 81 here). In the calculation they have not used the sample size anywhere. How is this possible ? As far as i know, in the formula itself the sample size is used.

Comment: If your solution did not use the value of 81, it's wrong.

Comment: I added backslashes before the dollar signs (which fixes formattting) and adjusted the numbers, as you had commas in odd places.  I doubt that there are towns where the average price is \$22,000,000 !

Comment: What solution do you have? Even if it is from a textbook, it could be wrong. Errors creep in. (I have edited an algebra book and a statistics book, both had many errors, and I probably did not get them all).

Comment: I got the solution from a reputed senior. It was his solution.

Comment: It's very hard to guess exactly what you're looking at; there are multiple possibilities. I see several possible explanations: (i) the 81 may have been present in a way you didn't recognize (e.g. it might have been there in terms of its square root, 9), or (ii) the solution contains a simple mistake that the person who did it would recognize as soon as they looked at it closely, or (iii) the reputation you mention is perhaps not quite so well deserved

Comment: I have tried both with 81 and without like he did. Answer is different. So, the basic thing I am taking away from this thread is that we must consider the sample size in our calculation. Thanks for helping out.